# update node properties using map without remove existing properties

Tags: java, neo4j

Is there any way to update a node using a map and don't remove existing properties?

Eg: my node props are:

```
{
   id   : 123,
   name : "foo"
}
```

Now I need send a map for the same id, but with different properties:

```
{
   id   : 123,
   age  : 30
}
```

If I do this, the **name** property will be erased from the node.

I can't set properties manually because they are dynamic and can be different for each request.

**UPDATE:** I'm doing this by sending Cypher query with params to REST API.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to do this in cypher or in the java api? Or over rest? (Maybe you could update your question to make that clear.)

Answer (score 0):

MERGE is your friend for updating.

Something along the lines of:

```
{ "query" : "MERGE (n:Node {id: {idValue}}) ON MATCH SET n.age = {ageValue}",
  "params" : { "idValue" : "123", "ageValue" : "30"}
}
```

...and send that to the Cypher endpoint.

http://docs.neo4j.org/refcard/2.0/ has the MERGE details.

http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/rest-api-cypher.html will help with sending REST params.

Comment: i'm using merge in query, but the question is about updating entire map without remove existing properties

Comment: And the answer above won't remove anything.  It simply adds to an existing node if it finds it.

Comment: what I want is a way to just pass the entire map once without writing each property in the query. I do this by `SET n = params.entire_map` but it will remove all existing properties.

Comment: Ah, I see.  Yeah, I don't know of any way to pass an entire map without having it remove any existing properties.  I'm not sure Cypher currently supports it.  Perhaps someone from the Neo crew can confirm/correct.

Comment: There is just now a pull request with a SET n += {map} syntax for Neo4j 2.1, so probably you'll get what you want in the next milestone.